# How to update a fragment TextView from an Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

If I have a function which gets different values from time-to-time and, using a fragment as display, I would like to update a TextView inside the fragment as the value varies, how could I manipulate the TextView from the fragment inside the MainActivity?

To clarify more:

My MainActivity veryfies the value inside DatabaseReference as follows:

```
userLoggedInRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.child("office").getValue(String.class).equals("none")) {
                officeKeyLoggedIn = dataSnapshot.child("office").getValue(String.class);
                usersInOffice.child(officeKeyLoggedIn).child(userKey).setValue("").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            /new-code/
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        ...
```

So here is the condition when a user enters an office and the value changes from "none" to "/officeKey/" and at this point I want to call on "/new-code/" the fragment, which is the display of the MainActivity, to set the visibility of a hidden TextView to VISIBLE and set it's text to something informing the user that he is now logged in.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT1: [MainActivity](https://pastebin.com/VprWr8rN)  [InicioFragment](https://pastebin.com/WfyH9qC6)

Comment: Move this logic to a shared ViewModel which is something you can see in the code provided as solution for https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#5 that way you no longer need to care about whether it is the Activity or the Fragment because it will be shared to both via Observer pattern

Comment: @on-my-way-to-dev-life are you trying to pass data from Activity to Fragment?

Comment: @Boken no, I'm trying to manipulate a textview from a fragment inside an activity

Comment: `TextView` is in `Activity`. Would you like to set text (in this `TextView`) FROM `Fragment`, right?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'll check your answer later, right now I don't have time to implement (I'll delete this too)

Comment: @Boken Nono, `TextView` is inside fragment, and the fragment is called from `MainActivity` via `onNavigationItemSelected` (as menu option)

Comment: OK, so `TextView` is in `Fragment`. Would you like to set text (in this `TextView`) FROM `Activity`?

Comment: @Boken Yes! The `TextView` is inside the `Fragment`, and as the `Activity` changes, I want the `Activity` to call this `TextView` of the `Fragment` to change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190923/discussion-between-boken-and-on-my-way-to-dev-life).

Comment: To be clear your TextView is part of Fragment or Activity?

Comment: @RohitSingh The TextView is part of the Fragment, it is declared inside the Fragment

Comment: @Boken code is correct.

Comment: Eventually you'll have to implement what I said, whether you use ViewModel to do it or something else is up to you though

Answer (score 3):

### In you Activity

You have to initialize this Fragment (e.g. as field):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Instance of our fragment
    OwnFragment fragment = new OwnFragment();

}
```

> Remember to use **exactly this instance** for transaction (using `FragmentManager`)

### In Fragment:

Next in your fragment you can create new method which receive data:

```
public class OwnFragment extends Fragment {

    // So you can pass there: View.VISIBLE, View.GONE or View.INVISIBLE
    void setVisibility(int visibility) {
        textView.setVisibility(visibility);
    }

    // Your new method
    void setNewText(String text) {
        textView.setText(text);
    }

}
```

### Again in Activity:

You can just call this method, using above instance of the Fragment:

```
fragment.setNewText("Hello world");
```

Comment: Boken, it's giving the error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference"

Comment: The function inside the `Fragment` is public void setTxtOfficeLoggedIn(String officeName) {
        txtOfficeLoggedIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtOfficeLoggedIn.setText("Você está logado em: " + officeName);
    }

Comment: Even if the first line (txtOfficeLoggedIn.setVisibility(...)) is commented, the error says `null object reference`

Comment: Are you using that same fragment? Would you modify your question and add code of your Activity (part with `fragmentManager`) and Fragment?

Comment: Did you forget to mention
" TextView textView - (TextView)findViewbyId(R.id.<id_name>)  ; " ?

Comment: @shellym no, it is declared on the Fragment, see the code now on the question